# .ui-btn List Of Attributes in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

Is there resource anywhere that lists classes for .ui-btn ? I know of .ui-btn-text and .ui-btn-active , etc. but does anyone have or know of a list that has all of the possible attributes that can be altered?

Comment: All of the possible attributes, what do you mean?

Comment: I can't find the `.ui-btn` class in the jQuery UI CSS style-sheet, did you mean jQuery Mobile?

Comment: Yes, jQuery Mobile, I edited it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You tagged your question as jQuery UI but those class names are associated with jQuery Mobile (I can't find `.ui-btn` in the jQuery UI style-sheet).

You can just look at the non-minified version of the jQuery Mobile 1.0 CSS style-sheet: http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.css (it's very well formatted and easy to read)

Just search for `.ui-btn` and you will see all the other classes associated.

It appears there is `.ui-btn`, `.ui-btn-up`, `.ui-btn-down`, `.ui-btn-hover`.

If you did mean jQuery UI then here is the un-minified version of the jQuery UI style-sheet: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css

Comment: Ah I see, I was trying to find that stuff but I was only looking at the ui-btn references in the "theme" sections as opposed to the plethora of code near the end of the css that dealt with the other attributes.

Answer (score 0):

The markup output looks like this:

```
<button class="ui-button ui-button-text-only ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
   <span class="ui-button-text">Button Label</span>
</button>
```

And you can find the other interactions states and cues in the CSS Framework reference:

> http://jqueryui.com/docs/Theming/API

Finally, check the stylesheet that you downloaded along with the UI code; if you didn't download one, get one here:

> http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/